# Is it possible to change the signature on the GMail email client?

Tags: android, gmail

Is it possible to change programmatically the email's signature from the GMail client application? Like the: *Sent from my iPhone* signature. I know this is kind of intrusive and agressive but I am just curious about whether this is possible (Where do you think the email signature is stored? Is it possible to change it, even with a hack?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot do this through your app. No app can edit another app's preferences using the Android SDK.

You may be able to do it if it is a rooted device, your app has root access, and if you know exactly where and in what format (SharedPreferences, SQLite) Gmail stores the signature.

But I would **strongly** advise you to not do this, as such an invasion of a user's privacy is going to put you on a highway to being uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally possible with Google Apps Email Settings API.
Check it out here:
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#manage_signature_settings

Note that you are not actually changing the signature for the phone's gmail but for that user's gmail in general, so might not exactly be what you are looking for...

[EDIT]: Note that this applies only to Google Apps for your own domain (and not gmail.com). Sorry if I confused anyone...